# How to terminate android application while debugging in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

When i right click in the debug perspective and select Terminate, Eclipse disconnects, but the process continues to run on the device.  How can i get the program to actually terminate so no more code is executed on the device?  Am i looking at a bug?  I dont recall if this worked in Galileo.  I am currently using Windows 7 and Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Button "Stop Process" is in device view (Window >> Show view >> Devices). [image]

Comment: Sometimes it's under Window >> Show view >> Other... >> Devices

Comment: Just started the app right after the project creation and when clicking stop button it did not kill the process but threw a `RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification` in the _logCat viewport_ `:(`

Answer (score 2):

> How can i get the program to actually terminate so no more code is executed on the device?

You can terminate the process from the DDMS perspective.

> Am i looking at a bug?

Not really. Terminate from the Debug perspective has always meant "terminate the debug session" for Android apps at least, not "terminate the app" or "terminate the app's author with extreme prejudice". :-)

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I gave the answer to the one that specifically calls out which button to use, and its not tied to the DDMS perspective (although anyone who has enough eclipse experience would know this).  I agree, not a bug, however i was misdirected in thinking that the Stop icon would stop the process.  Its a good clarification that Stop in the Debugger context is for the Debugger only, and not the process.  I was used to the Visual Studio IDE where stop killed the debugger and the process.

Comment: @Nick: "its not tied to the DDMS perspective" -- true. I tend to think in terms of "what would a newcomer want", and I find that it is easier for them to flip between perspectives than to maintain lots of views in one. But you are certainly correct, and if you want to just hit the Devices view from whatever perspective you'd like, that's perfectly cool.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newcomer to android. I found out that the normal way to stop all previously installed and still running apps (as it actually planned to be) at the avd, is to restart  avd with "Wipe user data" option checked. Maria

Answer (score -1):

Clicking on this disconnect button pointed in the image below.

You can open debug window from window>>open perspective..

[image: debugging window]